# ADB2C- use a login_hint on external Azure Active Directory sign-in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

We have implemented an **external Azure AD** integration using a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).  We want to change the process where we display a textbox first where we ask for the email, check if the email domain has integration with our system and display an error if it doesn't or continue with microsoft sign-in if it does.  We don't want the user to enter their email twice if integration exists.  Is there a way to use a **login_hint** with microsoft sign in?  There are no input claims in the technical profile to use the claim resolver **{OIDC:LoginHint}** on.

Thanks!

Comment: This sample shows how to use login_hint - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

Comment: Thanks but what I was asking is how to use it on external azure ad sign in policy that doesn't have any input claims in the technical profile.

Comment: It does use input claim on the AAD technical profile so the user doesnt need to enter email twice. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern/policy/SignIn_smart_HRD.xml#L150